# Iterating over ArrayList with Iterator where while condition searches for .contains() and fails

Tags: java, iterator

This shouldn't be rocket sience but for some reason my while-condition stays false. I create an empty  `ArrayList` which I fill. However when I iterate over it, it seems to fail. What am I missing?

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   names.add("Name " + i);
}
    
Iterator<String> it = names.iterator();
while(it.hasNext() && it.next().contains("Name 5")) {
    System.out.println("Found my desired name.");
}
```

Executed the appended code as-is in Netbeans.

Comment: Think about it. You get the first value from the list and compare it to `"Name 5"`. If the first value isn't `"Name 5"`, what would the loop do?

Comment: @Rogue it would go to the next item since i call the `.next()` method.

Comment: only if the condition evaluates to `true` which yours do not

Comment: Ohh, right.... pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code snippet for your problem would be

```
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            names.add("Name " + i);
        }

        Iterator<String> it = names.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String item = it.next();
            if (item.contains("Name 5")) {
                System.out.println("Found my desired name.");
                break;//remove if you don't want to exit
            }
        }
```

The problem with your code is the while loop.

`while(it.hasNext() && it.next().contains("Name 5")) {`

This basically means while the iterator has a value and the next value(which will be the first element in this case) contains Name 5, keep running. The problem with this is, that the first item will be "Name 0" not "Name 5". "Name 0" does not contain Name 5.

So what happens is that the condition for the while loop to run will be false and the loop  won't run.

Answer (score 0):

For the first iteration, `it.next()` returns the first element of the list, which is `Name 0`, so it never enters the `while` loop.

You should fix the code this way:

```
Iterator<String> it = names.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if (it.next().contains("Name 5")) {
        System.out.println("Found my desired name.");
        break; // exit while loop
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to break the looping. The list contains 10 elements only

Comment: @YegorSaliev Yes, but the correct solution is to exit the loop, so that the list size doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

`while` cycle will loop until your condition is not  true.
In your example it is `true && false` - will stop the looping